# Hidden searchbar slides down when view shown second time

Tags: uitableview, ios6, uiscrollview

I use the following code to hide searchbar:

```
- (void)updateContentOffset
{
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 44);
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self searchBarShouldEndEditing:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar];
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateContentOffset) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];

    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 44, 1, 1) animated:YES];
}
```

The code works perfectly when view is shown for the first time.

Next time it's shown(returning from another controller) it slides a bit down than it should be and I have no idea why it happens.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, in my case I played with a delay and found that making it 0.1 makes it work as planned.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(updateContentOffset) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```